# Hash URL with loader div in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, load

I have been created the hash URL load function through javascript. I am facing an issue that is I am not able to show loading div when I click on `href` tags.

My code is working fine and it only shows the loading div as `<div class="loader"><div>` when I reload the page but it not working on the click link.

Please help me, How I implement the function when clicking on the hash link.

```js
function loadcontent(hash) {
  if (hash == "") {
    hash = "./default-page.html";
  }
  $("html body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, "600", "swing");
  $("div.main-content-inner").load("pagefolder/" + hash);
}

$(window).on("hashchange", function() {
  loadcontent(location.hash.slice(1));
});

var url = window.location.href;
var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1);
if (hash === url) {
  hash = "./default-page.html";
}
$("body").append('<div class="loader"><div>');
$("body> div").load("pages/mypage/" + hash, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, jqXHR) {
  if (statusTxt == "success") {
    $("div.loader").remove();
  } else {
    if (statusTxt == "error") {
      $("div.loader").remove();
      alert("Error : " + jqXHR.status + " " + jqXHR.statusText);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#home">home</a>
<a href="#about">about</a>
<a href="#contactus">contact us</a>
```

Comment: You remove the loader in first `load()` callback and never insert it again when you call `loadcontent()`

Comment: I am a beginner and created the above code very slowly slowly, pls help me how I make it perfect in fiddle sir..